# Can't figure out how to retrieve objects in a map

Tags: java

I have a

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap;
```

I'm having a hard time retrieving the objects in the List:
For example I can retrieve from the Map

```
String myString = myMap.get("Toyota").toString();
```

but how do I retrieve from the List?
Lets say that the List contains all the models for each car brand. How can I retrieve only the item 0 in that that List?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the API of `List`? You need to do - `myMap.get("Toyota").get(0)`?

Comment: @RohitJain that'd be better suited as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myMap.get("Toyota").get(0)` - That should do it.
The reason is that you ask `myMap` the value that is pointed by the key "Toyota". As you defined in your definitions, the values are always of type `List<String>` which means that the call `myMap.get("Toyota")` returns a `List<String>` object. When you do a `get(0)` call you actually call the `get` method of `List<String>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the `List` and then its contents :

```
//myMap.get(key).get(listIndex);
// myMap.get("Toyota"); // gets the List object
myMap.get("Toyota").get(0);
```

Hence , you need to use [Map#get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) and then [List#get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

The statement `myMap.get("Toyota")` will return the `List` type which is value for the key `Toyota`. You can get the first element of list using `myMap.get("Toyota").get(0)`

Comment: List may not be an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you use a Map and want to retrieve values based on certain key, you can iterate over the Map and retrieve them as follows :

```
for (final Entry<String, List<String>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<String> value = entry.getValue();
}
```

As you can see, inside the for loop, you have both key and the value. You can do the further processing here after.